# Which return type for NoContent HTTP response?

Tags: c#, .net-core

What is the correct return type for **DELETE** HTTP actions when returning a `NoContent` response?

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent, Type = typeof(User))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<void>> DeleteUserById(Guid id)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Of course I can't use that because `void` can't be used as a type. But I can't use this either

```
    public async void DeleteUserById(Guid id)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
```

because I'm returning something.

Comment: `Task<ActionResult>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to return `NoContent()` you should use a prototype like this (remove `void`):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteUserById(Guid id)
{
    return NoContent();
}
```